# JS <select> listbox not working on click/change

Tags: javascript, html-select

what I need to do is to gather some data online via fetch and use the data to give the user infos and such (that I can do). In some cases, the fetch can return multiple results (an array of data), so I decided to create a  element in the page to list all the names of the elements in the array (each element in the array is a sub-array with various infos, also a "name", which would be a location name).

I'm working on Chrome. All works, I store the data and this way I created another function to (theoretically) give the user the infos about the selected option in the  listbox. If I call the function directly it works fine, meaning it returns all the infos it should. What actually doesn't work is the fact that this function returning infos should trigger on click/selecting any option from the list and it doesn't work. I don't get any error messages, it just does nothing.

What you see in this image is what happens when you click "filter" (it actually filters world locations detected with name similar to "Milano"), the user gets infos in the page and what you see in the right log side in the red square is returning the content of that array I mentioned (it contains data, so it's working), the index selected in the list (the last, so it's 5) and the coordinates of such selected location.
[image]

This happens just after the creation of the options because I directly call the function (returning data about the selected option), but if I use manually the list it just does nothing (as you see in the list, there's nothing logged after those coordinates).

I tried to create the options like this:

```
function createOption(text){
  let listOption = new Option(text, text, true, true);
  return listOption;
}
```

What I do directly to create the options in the list is a "for" loop for each element i in the array:

```
document.getElementById("keyword-results").append(createOption(data.data[i].station.name));
```

I also tried appendChild instead of append. As I said, this works, but the manual use of the list doesn't. What I declared is:

```
document.getElementById("keyword-results").addEventListener("onchange", selection());
```

being "selection()" the function returning the data.

```
function selection(){
  let index = document.getElementById("keyword-results").selectedIndex;
  console.log(index);
  if (index > -1){
    let currentResult = results.data[index];
    let aqi = currentResult.aqi;
    console.log(aqi);
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += `The estimated AQI [...]`;
    let far = distance(currentResult.station.geo[0], currentResult.station.geo[1]);
    if (far != null || far != undefined) {
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += `The estimated distance [...]`;
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried "change", "onclick" and "click" as methods to trigger the function but none of them works. Do you have any suggestions? I can't find anything useful here on stackoverflow nor on the web. If you want to check the whole code, this is my GitHub repository https://github.com/leorob88/pollution-forecast-API

Answer (score 1):

I see you add text trying to "update" the `innerHTML` of the element. Try this: store all the text content you need into a `string` variable and instead of adding content to the `innerHTML` every time you just need to set the `innerHTML` to the variable. Meaning, instead of

```
div.innerHTML += "random-text";
div.innerHTML += "random-text";
```

you can try this

```
textVariable = "text-you-need";  //keep updating textVariable as you need
div.innerHTML = textVariable;    //last row of code
```

Comment: Actually I already managed to do this a while ago, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("keyword-results").addEventListener("onchange", selection());
```

addEventListener expects a function as a second parameter, selection() is not a function but selection is.

When you use `addEventListener`, there is no such event named `onchange` its actually `change`

so it becomes:

```
document.getElementById("keyword-results").addEventListener("change", selection);
```

[Reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Comment: And that didn't change anything (seems wrong to me, though, writing without ()), not even "onclick"...

Comment: addEventListener expects a function as a second parameter, `selection()` is not a function but `selection` is. Also, I didn't notice at first hand but there is no such event named `onchange` or `onclick` when you use addEventListener they are named `click` and `change`, updated the answer to reflect on that

Comment: despite this, none of these works:

```document.getElementById("keyword-results").addEventListener("change", selection);``` ```document.getElementById("keyword-results").addEventListener("change", selection, false);```
(the repository is constantly updated as I try to solve this matter)